# Testing application with different windows

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging

I am developing A WPF application in VS Comunity 2015 on Windows 7. Everything works fine.
But when I run the app on Windows 10, very odd bugs appeared and I have no way to figure out why, since the laptop that is using W10 is too slow to run VS.

Is there a way to somehow run the debugger in Windows 10 or any other way to find the problems?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Maybe you can try [remote debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx)

Comment: You can use other IDE to debug in that Win10 PC. May be codeBlocks or Visual Code.

Comment: Will check it out. Thanks